# Sidekiq current Celluloid Actor

Tags: ruby, sidekiq, celluloid

I need to access the current celluloid actor inside of my Sidekiq worker, but I don't see a way to do that.

Whenever I try to call:

```
Celluloid::Actor.current
```

I get an error: `not in actor scope`

I tried to get around finding the current actor by creating a new one every time with:

```
Celluloid::Actor.new(SecureRandom.hex)
```

But for some reason it was giving me an error of `attempted to call dead actor`.

**What should I be doing differently to get the current actor inside of a Sidekiq worker?**

**Background Info**
 I am connecting to a websocket in my worker and sending messages to it.

`Celluloid::WebSocket::Client.new('ws://my-uri', Celluloid::Actor.current)`

Comment: Why do you need to do that?

Comment: Good question, I didn't think it was relevant to the question. But I am connecting to a websocket in my worker and sending messages to it. `@websocket_client ||= Celluloid::WebSocket::Client.new('ws://my-uri', Celluloid::Actor.current)`

Comment: Are you sure you want to use workers? Maybe all you need is a simple daemon?

Comment: Unfortunately I do need to use workers. Good idea though!

Comment: Good luck with it then. Hope you'll solve this :)

Answer (score 1):

Guess you should define a separate class including Celluloid, here's an example based on [one of those from Sidekiq repo](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/master/examples/sinkiq.rb)

```
class MyWebSocketWhatever
  include Celluloid

  def initialize(url)
    @ws_client = Celluloid::WebSocket::Client.new url, Celluloid::Actor.current
  end

  def send_message(msg)
    @ws_client.text msg
  end

  def on_message(msg)
    $redis.lpush 'sinkiq-example-messages', "RESPONSE: #{msg}"
  end
end

class SinatraWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(msg='lulz you forgot a msg!')
    $redis.lpush 'sinkiq-example-messages', "SENT: #{msg}"
    MyWebSocketWhatever.new('ws://echo.websocket.org').send_message msg
  end
end
```

Works like a charm, just finished playing with it. Get [the full updated example](https://gist.github.com/utgarda/6157547), install required gems, then start both Sinatra and Sidekiq

```
sidekiq -r ./sinkiq.rb
ruby ./sinkiq.rb
```

then browse to `http://localhost:4567`